# If Internet goes down while we make a Ajax Request then how to give feedback to the user that the internet is down?

Tags: ajax

If Internet goes down while we make a Ajax Request then how to give feedback to the user that the internet is down ?

Comment: If the Internet goes down, we have bigger problems.

Comment: If the internet goes down, how is the user seeing your site?

Comment: @Oded because the user opened the webpage before connexion goes down... so when user do something on the webapp AJAX request fail...

Comment: @Alois Cochard - And so will email, all other websites and refreshes of the current page.

Comment: @Oded, yes but what's your point here ? ... imagine if the webapp is user's main business activity, he will probably notice that internet is down by using the app instead of checking email or twitter... and if app is mainly AJAX .. refresh must occur rarely.

Comment: @Alois Cochard - my point is that if the Internet is down, the user will notice it is down, including the web app.

Comment: @Oded your optimist ;-) just imagine your *lambda* user is in a train with 3G connection ... or with any -not so reliable- connection...

Answer (score 1):

You can define a timeout on AJAX request, if timeout is reached you can then choose best way to display the error message to the user.

BTW, you cannot be certain that internet connection is down, so a standard message could be:

*Unable to contact server at url: 'http://myapp.com'.

Please be sure your internet connection is working*

Answer (score 1):

The ajax request will time out and fail at which point you could let the user know and suggest to them that their internet connection might be down.

You will only be able to suggest as there is no way of knowing what has severed the connection from the client to your host. It could be your server is down or their net is down right through to it could be their ISP is having intermittent failures.

Answer (score 0):

If an AJAX call fails, and you are 100% sure that it will fail only if there is no internet connection, then after failure you can make, for example, a popup informing the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example which will make you work of detecting the user is online or offline very easily

[Checking for online and offline events to detect connectivity status for the end user.](http://robertnyman.com/html5/offline/online-offline-events.html)

Hope it helps